# Can we transfer fund from personal account to business accont via php api

Tags: php, api, paypal

I have to transfer fund from personal account to business account in paypal using mass pay account in PHP.

The actual problem is when we transfer fund form business account we have to give three credential like user name, password, signature.

In personal account we don't have signature to transfer fund from business pay pal account.

I just need the help if it is possible.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the API documentation for PayPal? All the methods listed there would allow you to determine if the procedures you seek are available via the API.

Comment: Yes i have reviewed the document but i am not getting is it possible or not or How is it possible ?

Comment: You won't be able to use MassPay API on a Personal account, only in Premier or Business accounts.

Also, note that MassPay would need to be enabled in such accounts, as per the documentation.